# JavaScript if array contains name then dont do it

Tags: javascript

So I have this piece of code:

```
if(item.name != "Banana" || "Apple"){
console.log("Good job");
} else{
console.log("Mad");
}
```

Basically, that part doesn't work `!=` it still goes with those names. Doesn't ignore them.

Comment: if you have an array you need a loop

Comment: And where's the array? Also, it's `if(item.name != "Banana" && item.name != "Apple"){`

Comment: I got loop, I just added part what doesn't work.

Comment: The `||` operator won't do what you think it will in that comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Apple"];
if( fruits.indexOf(item.name) != -1 ){
    console.log("name is banana or apple")
} else {
    console.log("name is neither banana nor apple")
}
```

is this what you are looking for?

Anyway

```
if(item.name != "Banana" || "Apple")
```

this piece of code will always evaluate "Banana" over "Apple" as the `or` operator works with the first argument that is not falsy. "Banana" is evaluated as true then the if condition will always be

```
if (item.name != "Banana")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw another option out there, you can filter an array through the use of higher order functions, in this case the builtin array's `filter` function:

```
var withoutApplesAndBanans = myArray.filter( function(item) { 
     return item.name !== 'Apple' && item.name !== 'Banana'; 
} );
```

You could also build an array of 'forbidden' words, and use that instead of a hard comparison:

```
var forbiddenWords = ['Apple, 'Banana'];

var withoutApplesAndBanans = myArray.filter( item => forbiddenWords.indexOf(item.name) === -1 ) ;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better then with `var not = !array.some(function(x) {return x === item.name;});`